# PC user wants Windows/Linux key mappings

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

I'm a long-time PC and Linux user. Recently, I was given a mac mini (Yosemite) for my job. I've still got my full-size PC keyboard (with number pad).

There are several differences. The biggest one is control key is used as command on windows. The physical location of command (right below ZXCV keys) is physically discomforting for me to use.  It's just too tight of a space for two of my sausage fingers to fit in. So I remapped the ctrl-key to command. This works, and is comfortable, except when I need to use control, because I do a lot of terminal stuff (ctrl-X(background), D(EOF), C(break),O) I don't know where I remap actual control to.  I thought option as alt, but that does not work.

Additionally I use home and end keys quite a lot in terminal or chrome, and these don't function as in windows. Hitting end while typing in this box, it takes me to the bottom of the page. Hitting end in terminal takes me to the end of the scroll-back buffer. Previously, on my PC it would take me to the end of the current command, not the top of the scroll-back buffer.

Modifier keys (Sys Prefs: Keyboard: Modifier Keys):

> CAPS: CAPS
>
> Control: Command
>
> Option: Option
>
> Command: Control

Right of backspace I have:

> Ins Home PgUp
>
> Del End PgDn

Bottom Row of keys:

> Ctrl Win Alt Space Alt Menu Ctrl

To recap:

1. Can I use Ctrl for both Option and Ctrl (when I set Ctrl to both Command and Control, it only does one)
2. How can I get home and end to work per line, not per screen

I' don't mind remapping the terminal key, is that is possible, though I am using iTerm as well as regular terminal.

Many thanks!

Comment: For the record, the Karabiner answer is really the one I wanted. The remapping in Modifier keys is incomplete. Like I said in my question , remapping command to control only gets you so far, then control is broken when you really need control.

Answer (score 0):

There are few 3d party application that can remap the keyboard to your liking.

An example is the [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

[image: Karabiner]

More simpler is if you just want to remap the control keys.

That can be done in the system preferences- Keyboard.

[image: keyboard map]